# Why junit included part of hamcrest in binary, but not in source

Tags: java, open-source, junit, hamcrest

Ok, so [here](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/downloads) is the place to download junit. Open any compiled jar - there is package org.hamcrest. Open any source-jar - there is no such package.
It is very strange since sources for hamcrest are available at [googlecode](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/source/checkout).

So, is there any reason for this except making inconveniences to users?

How do you deal with this, or just don't look in these sources in your IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, is there any reason for this except making inconveniences to users?

Yea ... they do it to test your ability to use Google :-).

Seriously, Hamcrest is not part of JUnit, so I guess that Kent Beck doesn't see it as his role to distribute Hamcrest source code.  But why are you asking **us** about this?  Why don't you ask the man himself?

> How do you deal with this ...

Personally, I use Maven and Eclipse with the m2eclipse plugin.  M2eclipse automatically downloads source code on demand; e.g. the first time I navigate to a class.

Before that, I used to Google stuff and download by hand.

Be thankful that you can get all of these open source tools for free ... and that the source code is actually available.

Comment: Download section of this site - is the link that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes, it appeared that in maven there is hamcrest sources inside junit for [4.8.2](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2-sources.jar) (link to the jar-file) but no sources in the version [4.8.1](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1-sources.jar) Now I understand that they already addressed that inconvenience and resolved it.

Comment: @Ivan Sopov - like I said above, you are talking to the wrong people.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a source jar you normally distribute your own sources, not that of others.
The hamcrest classes being packaged in the binary jar seems just to be a convenience for the user not having to add the hamcrest jars to the classpath.

Comment: Isn't sources in jar are just convinience to view sources, but not to build them? I have not seen any build instructions or maven/ant/gradle configurations in source jars. And since they are packaging third-party class files in their distribution - why not package the source of that class files in the source-jar? I think it is pretty complex to find the exact version of sources from which these class files were compiled on the official hamcrest site.

Comment: @Ivan yes, source jars are a convenience, too. Getting the exact sources might be hard, but JUnit should state the version of hamcrest they're using somewhere. Then take the sources of that version.

Comment: @Thomas - Maven answers that question.  Just look at the dependencies in the POM file.

Comment: @Stephen - Yes, if you have a pom for JUnit, you'll see the version there - and maybe also the "jar-with-dependencies" goal (don't remember the exact name). Afaik, there's no such goal for source jars - at least no widely used one - thus the difference. And as stated, the version should be found somewhere, be it a pom.xml, an ivy.xml or somewhere on their web page. I too wanted to test Ivan's google capacities :)